# How to work for the regular expression "a*b*a+" based NFA

Tags: node.js, regex, parsing, graph, nfa

#### I wrote a simple regular expression parser in JS,the parser only supports "*" and "+",then I found a problem.

#### The result of "aa" matching /a*b*a+/ is wrong.

Here's my process.

1. First of all,I new a NFA graph by the RE string.

   [image: my NFA graph]
   As shown,the state 5 has a counter,if the counter >= 1,state 5 will point "_end",the graph will be connected.
2. Start from state 0 and do DFS,record each visited node.
3. Match the string,if the two are equal,the next state's counter +1,and do DFS start from the next state.
4. When the string ended,check the visited node,if it has state 6,return true,else return false.

This is my code.

```js
var Graph = require(__dirname + '/../Graph.js');
var DFS = require(__dirname + '/../DFS.js');

var NFA = module.exports = function(regexp) {
    var ops = new Array(); // stack
    this.re = regexp;
    this.M = this.re.length;
    this.G = new Graph(this.M + 1, regexp);

    for (var i = 0; i < this.M; i++) {
        if (this.re[i] == '*' || this.re[i] == '+') {
            this.G.addEdge(i, i - 1);
            this.G.addEdge(i - 1, i);
        }
        if (this.re[i] == '*')
            this.G.addEdge(i, i + 1);
    }
};

NFA.prototype.recognize = function(txt) {
    var pc = new Array();
    var dfs = new DFS(this.G, 0);
    for (var v = 0; v < this.G.getV(); v++) {
        if (dfs.marked[v] == true) {
            pc.push(v);
        }
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < txt.length; i++) {
        var match = new Array();
        for (var v = 0; v < pc.length; v++) {
            if (pc[v] < this.M) {
                if (this.re[pc[v]] == txt[i]) {
                    match.push(pc[v] + 1);
                    this.G.counter[pc[v] + 1]++;
                    var cnt = this.G.counter[pc[v] + 1]++;
                    if (cnt == 1) {
                        this.G.addEdge(pc[v] + 1, pc[v] + 2);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        pc = new Array();
        dfs = new DFS(this.G, match);
        for (var v = 0; v < this.G.getV(); v++) {
            if (dfs.marked[v] == true) {
                pc.push(v);
            }
        }
    }
    for (var v = 0; v < pc.length; v++) {
        if (pc[v] == this.M) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
};
```

Result:

- "aa" match /a*b*a+/ true
- "aab" match /a*b*a+/ true (It should be false)
- **"aab" match /a*b*aa*/ false (It's my  provisional processing method)**
- "aa" match /a*b*aa*/ true

I want to know how to do can fix this bug,I don't want use the provisional processing method.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to support backtracking on the * and + operators, and it's not obvious to me that your code does that.

Comment: Take a look at the NFA construction in [Russ Cox's useful essay](https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html) and look at the difference between `*` and `+` operators. Attaching a count to a state is almost certainly not what you want, since you cannot do DFS easily if the state of the graph changes during the search.

Comment: What's wrong with "aa" matching /a*b*a+/ ? The stars match zero length strings and a+ the whole string